# Data Grouping in R (Akin to Summation with a WHERE clause in SQL)

Tags: sql, r, sum, aggregate, where-clause

I am having a challenge grouping data in R using the **aggregate** command. I can do this with SQL relatively easily, but I am not able the get the same effect with R.

As an example, here is a test set of data, that in SQL provides the essence of what I am looking for:

```
create table #data(v1 varchar(4), v2 int, v3 int, v4 int,v5 int)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 3, 8, 7, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 4, 9, 8, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 5, 10, 9, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 6, 11, 7, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 7, 12, 8, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 3, 13, 9, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 4, 14, 7, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 5, 8, 8, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 6, 9, 9, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 7, 10, 7, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 3, 11, 8, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 4, 12, 9, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 5, 13, 7, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 6, 14, 8, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 7, 8, 9, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 3, 9, 7, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 4, 10, 8, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 5, 11, 9, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 6, 12, 7, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 7, 13, 8, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 3, 14, 9, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 4, 8, 7, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 5, 9, 8, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 6, 10, 9, 14)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8000, 7, 11, 7, 11)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8001, 3, 12, 8, 12)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8002, 4, 13, 9, 13)
insert #data(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) values(8003, 5, 14, 7, 14)

select * from #data

select v1, sum(v2)
from #data
    where v4 <= v3 and v5 > v3
group by v1

drop table #data
```

In R, I have tried using **aggregate** with a **subset** command, **aggregate** with an inline function(x)... and still have not been able to coalesce the data in the way I was hoping for in a purely 'R' manner. I am aware of the SQL library to allow SQL statements to be transacted upon a data structure, but I am looking to avoid that since I am pulling the data from a database in the first place, and if I need to resort to that, I might as well write the SQL to do it. I am looking for a purist R way of doing it. Perhaps it is a bit idealistic, but that is the hope and the dream.

Something to note with the clause is it is something of an exclusionary clause summing the data NOT included by the V2 variable in the current row. If it were otherwise, this would be a fairly simple problem for me, but I am not grepping the passing the current line under scrutiny's values to a function against the larger data set, or if another solution altogether would be better.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the R code to generate the test data:

```
m.data <- as.data.frame(
        cbind(8000:8003, 3:7, 8:14, 7:9, 11:14, 1:28),
        row.names=NULL
);
```

Comment: Instead of providing just SQL statements for the example data, why not show us the data in R? It would help if you provided the output from `dput(foo)` where `foo` is the object in R containing the data you show. `aggregate(subset(foo, v4 <= v3 & v5 > v3), by = list(v1), FUN = sum)` would at first blush seem to be what is wanted...

Comment: This issue with this is 1) the data set is huge, and 2) the information in the original data set is not for me to divulge, but if this example is solved, it will essentially solve the question I am asking. But, I will post the above in R, so at the very least you will be able to load the sample data more easily.

Comment: okay, posting it in the comments is not working so well, so I will add it to the above code.

Comment: Great... thanks for the code snippet, it looks good and may be exactly what I am looking for. I will run it over the data and post the results.

Comment: Okay, this is enlightening... I ran the modified code over my data set, and received an error, which I had seen before, so I ran it over the above example, and got the same error, namely:

Error in aggregate.data.frame(subset(m.data, V4 <= V3 & V5 > V3), by = list(V1),  : 
  arguments must have same length

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a toy example illustrating what Gavin described in the comments:

```
dd <- data.frame(v1 = rep(1:4,5),v2 = 1:20, 
                 v3 = runif(20), v4 = runif(20), v5 = runif(20))

#Extract the subset
dd_new <- subset(dd,v4 <= v3 & v5 > v3)

#Using the aggregate command...
> aggregate(dd_new$v2,list(v1=dd_new$v1),sum)
  v1  x
1  1 14
2  2 18
3  3 41
4  4 16

#Or the often popular ddply from plyr
> ddply(dd_new,.(v1),summarise,tot = sum(v2))
  v1 tot
1  1  14
2  2  18
3  3  41
4  4  16
```

I split up the subset from the aggregating for clarity, but as Gavin indicated you can roll it all into a single line if you like.

Comment: that looks good, I will try it on the original data set and post the results.

Comment: @TraivsRodman Glad to hear it. Just so you know, the reason we ask for reproducible examples (see what I did in my answer? that's what should have been in your question!) is to avoid exactly this kind of back-and-forth: I guess at an answer, you check and report back. When you inevitably say it didn't work, I have to guess again. So I hope you found this useful, but if it doesn't work and you want more help you'll have to edit your question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: joran - thanks for the information on the posting...
@Gavin - sorry for the back and forth, I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question.

This exactly solves the problem. The inclusion of the subset in the way you have described provides the right return data. I had tried making the subset an in-line argument, but it was not working for whatever reason, but this code is working exactly as I had hoped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

And if you are an SQL-junkie, try sqldf. It is very effective with large data sets. Note that I used mdata instead of m.data which needs escaping in SQL.

```
library(sqldf)
mdata <- as.data.frame(
        cbind(8000:8003, 3:7, 8:14, 7:9, 11:14, 1:28),
        row.names=NULL
);
sqldf("select v1, sum(v2) from mdata  where v4 <= v3 and v5 > v3 group by v1")
```